# Conditionally displaying server controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am tasked, in my group project, to create Profile page for all users. Our group has this thing going in ASP.net, with C# as backend. They put up something already for editing profile information. Page looks like this, so far: [image: I added side menu]

They didn't add side menu, but I did. What I want to do is to be able to, on click of different option, display different elements on the screen.

My ASP code looks like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_Profile" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <!-- Should this page be visible to only this user? -->
    <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name: "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="YourFirstNameLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="ChangeFirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="New First Name: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name: "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="YourLastNameLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="ChangeLastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="New Last Name: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="UpdateProfileButton" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateProfileButton_Click" Text="Update Profile" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent" Runat="Server">
    <p style="height: 151px">
        <asp:ListBox 
            id="ProfileSideMenu"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            SelectionMode="single"
            onSelectedIndexChanged="ProfileSideMenu_SelectionChanged"
            runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Edit Profile</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>View Profile</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>View Friends</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <!-- This is dummy label and will be discarded when all is said and done -->
        <asp:Label ID="DummyLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

My idea is to have server controls for "Edit profile" show up only when "Edit profile" is picked (and ultimately if loggedInUser is the user whose profile they are viewing. In PHP, this would be as simple as overwriting the contents of that element (via `echo`). However, I don't know how to overwrite server controls. (I found no documentation on how to do this.)

So far, my C# code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class User_Profile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static string EDIT_PROFILE = "Edit Profile",
        VIEW_PROFILE = "View Profile",
        VIEW_FRIENDS = "View Friends";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YourFirstNameLabel.Text = Profile.FirstName;
        YourLastNameLabel.Text = Profile.LastName;
    }

    protected void UpdateProfileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Profile.FirstName = Server.HtmlEncode(FirstNameTextBox.Text);
        YourFirstNameLabel.Text = Profile.FirstName;

        Profile.LastName = Server.HtmlEncode(LastNameTextBox.Text);
        YourLastNameLabel.Text = Profile.LastName;
    }

    // to be called when selection changes in ProfileSideMenu
    protected void ProfileSideMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the text of the option selected
        string listSelection = "";
        if (ProfileSideMenu.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            listSelection = ProfileSideMenu.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        // TODO: based on text, display the appropriate panel in #Content2
        if (listSelection != "")
        {
            // For right now, just display it in DummyLabel
            DummyLabel.Text = listSelection;
            if (listSelection == User_Profile.EDIT_PROFILE)
            {
                // TODO: Show only elements for "Edit Profile"
            }
            if (listSelection == User_Profile.VIEW_PROFILE)
            {
                // TODO: Show only elements for "View Profile"
            }
            if (listSelection == User_Profile.VIEW_FRIENDS)
            {
                // TODO: Show only elements for "View Friends"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DummyLabel.Text = "No selection";
        }
    }
}
```

I am a total newb at ASP.net....

Comment: In case this isn't clear, I want to show only respective elements in `Content2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this, but one option is to use a `MultiView` control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227665.aspx

Basically you'll define each section as a `View` and show the one you want.

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mvProfile" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="viewEditProfile" runat="server">
        <h3>Edit profile</h3>
        <%--- Edit profile controls ---%>           
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="viewViewProfile" runat="server">
        <h3>View profile</h3>
        <%--- View profile controls ---%>                       
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="viewViewFriends" runat="server">
        <h3>View Friends</h3>
        <%--- View friends profile controls ---%>           
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Next you adjust your if statements to change the `ActiveViewIndex`

```
if (listSelection == User_Profile.EDIT_PROFILE)
{
    // TODO: Show only elements for "Edit Profile"
    mvProfile.ActiveViewIndex = 0; // 0 for the first view
}
if (listSelection == User_Profile.VIEW_PROFILE)
{
    // TODO: Show only elements for "View Profile"
    mvProfile.ActiveViewIndex = 1; // 1 for the second view
}
if (listSelection == User_Profile.VIEW_FRIENDS)
{
    // TODO: Show only elements for "View Friends"
    mvProfile.ActiveViewIndex = 2; // 2 for the third view
}
```

There are quite a few ways to handle this, but this is just one example.

Comment: I was going to put visible attribute on all of those, and then toggle visible, which would have been way more work! Thanks; /* I'm going to try this! */

Comment: I have question about this: how should the [InvalidOperationException] be handled upon attempting to set `visible` on any of the views at runtime (for example, viewing someone else's Profile.aspx, and the code "hiding" their "edit profile" ?

[InvalidOperationException]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view.visible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You may want to just do a check on your if statements and only allow Edit mode if it's their Profile. You could also disable the left menu edit option when viewing someone else's profile to prevent them from selecting that.

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do, and I figured it out!